# is there a function that return false on 0 or other things but true on false,null, empty array()?

Tags: php, php-5.3

I think the simplest way would be `(!$var and $var!=0)`, but is there a way to do it without repeating the var name?

Comment: why can you not repeat the var name?

Comment: What are *other things*?

Comment: Other variables that give true normally like strings, or non empty arrays, objects, whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function foo($var)
{
    return ($var === false || $var === null || is_array($var));
}

if(foo($your_var)){}
```

Comment: Well i thought empty array that is array with no elements. Of course i don't expect any language to have that function or arbitrary array, but I thought there is a built in function that retrun everything as do it empty but without treating numeric zero as false.

Comment: @user393087: No, but you can easily create your own function and test for these values explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

`$var !== 0` satisfies your requests, it returns false on zero and true on everything else (including false, null and empty arrays).

Comment: But it should also return `false` for e.g. non-empty strings. OP is looking for a function that works like `empty` but not treating `0` as empty. `$var !== 0` does not suffice.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comment, I think this is what you want:

```
function really_empty($var) {
    return $var !== 0 && empty($var);
}
```

Comment: @downvoter: Please explain. Otherwise I don't know how to improve my answer. Thank you!